# directx11 simple application crashes

Tags: c++, directx-11

I'm developing a directx11 app and for some reason, my simple application crashes with an access violation error. Something causes it to crash and then my graphics drivers causes a reset.

Here's my initialization:

```
DirectXRendererImpl::DirectXRendererImpl(const EngineSettings& settings, Logger& logger) : mLogger(logger), mWindowHandle(GetActiveWindow()), mSwapchain(nullptr), mBackbuffer(nullptr), mDevice(nullptr), mContext(nullptr),
    mForwardVertexShader(nullptr), mForwardPixelShader(nullptr), mVertexBuffer(nullptr), mInputLayout(nullptr)
{
    // create swapchain, device and devicecontext
    DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC swapChainDesc;
    ZeroMemory(&swapChainDesc, sizeof(DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC));
    swapChainDesc.BufferCount = 2;
    swapChainDesc.BufferDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM;
    swapChainDesc.BufferUsage = DXGI_USAGE_RENDER_TARGET_OUTPUT;
    swapChainDesc.OutputWindow = mWindowHandle;
    swapChainDesc.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
    swapChainDesc.SampleDesc.Quality = 0;
    swapChainDesc.Windowed = true;

    const D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL featureLevel = D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_0;
    const UINT numFeatureLevels = 1;

    HRESULT result = D3D11CreateDeviceAndSwapChain(NULL, D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_HARDWARE, NULL, NULL, &featureLevel, numFeatureLevels, D3D11_SDK_VERSION, &swapChainDesc, &mSwapchain, &mDevice, NULL, &mContext);
    if (result != S_OK)
    {
        JONS_LOG_ERROR(mLogger, "DirectXRenderer::DirectXRenderer(): D3D11CreateDeviceAndSwapChain failed: code " + result);
        throw std::runtime_error("DirectXRenderer::DirectXRenderer(): D3D11CreateDeviceAndSwapChain failed: code " + result);
    }

    // backbuffer rendertarget setup
    ID3D11Texture2D* backbuffer = nullptr;
    mSwapchain->GetBuffer(0, __uuidof(ID3D11Texture2D), (LPVOID*)&backbuffer);

    mDevice->CreateRenderTargetView(backbuffer, NULL, &mBackbuffer);
    backbuffer->Release();

    mContext->OMSetRenderTargets(1, &mBackbuffer, NULL);

    // setup viewport
    // query width/height from d3d
    ZeroMemory(&swapChainDesc, sizeof(DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC));
    mSwapchain->GetDesc(&swapChainDesc);

    D3D11_VIEWPORT viewport;
    ZeroMemory(&viewport, sizeof(D3D11_VIEWPORT));
    viewport.TopLeftX = 0;
    viewport.TopLeftY = 0;
    viewport.Width = static_cast<float>(swapChainDesc.BufferDesc.Width);
    viewport.Height = static_cast<float>(swapChainDesc.BufferDesc.Height);
    viewport.MinDepth = 0.0f;
    viewport.MaxDepth = 1.0f;

    mContext->RSSetViewports(1, &viewport);

    // create shader objects
    mDevice->CreateVertexShader(gForwardVertexShader, sizeof(gForwardVertexShader), NULL, &mForwardVertexShader);
    mDevice->CreatePixelShader(gForwardPixelShader, sizeof(gForwardPixelShader), NULL, &mForwardPixelShader);

    mContext->VSSetShader(mForwardVertexShader, NULL, NULL);
    mContext->PSSetShader(mForwardPixelShader, NULL, NULL);

    // fill vertex buffer
    VERTEX OurVertices[] =
    {
        { 0.0f, 0.5f, 0.0f },
        { 0.45f, -0.5, 0.0f},
        { -0.45f, -0.5f, 0.0f }
    };

    D3D11_BUFFER_DESC bufferDescription;
    ZeroMemory(&bufferDescription, sizeof(D3D11_BUFFER_DESC));
    bufferDescription.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
    bufferDescription.ByteWidth = sizeof(OurVertices);
    bufferDescription.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_VERTEX_BUFFER;
    bufferDescription.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
    bufferDescription.MiscFlags = 0;

    D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA initData;
    ZeroMemory(&initData, sizeof(D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA));
    initData.pSysMem = OurVertices;

    mDevice->CreateBuffer(&bufferDescription, &initData, &mVertexBuffer);

    D3D11_INPUT_ELEMENT_DESC inputDescription;
    ZeroMemory(&inputDescription, sizeof(D3D11_INPUT_ELEMENT_DESC));
    inputDescription.SemanticName = "POSITION";
    inputDescription.SemanticIndex = 0;
    inputDescription.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32_FLOAT;
    inputDescription.InputSlot = 0;
    inputDescription.AlignedByteOffset = 0;
    inputDescription.InputSlotClass = D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA;
    inputDescription.InstanceDataStepRate = 0;

    mDevice->CreateInputLayout(&inputDescription, 1, gForwardVertexShader, sizeof(gForwardVertexShader), &mInputLayout);

    mContext->IASetInputLayout(mInputLayout);

    // register as window subclass to listen for WM_SIZE events. etc
    if (!SetWindowSubclass(mWindowHandle, WndProc, gSubClassID, 0))
    {
        JONS_LOG_ERROR(mLogger, "DirectXRenderer::DirectXRenderer(): SetWindowSubclass() failed");
        throw std::runtime_error("DirectXRenderer::DirectXRenderer(): SetWindowSubclass() failed");
    }

    gDirectXRendererImpl = this;
}
```

The simple vertex shader:

```
struct VOut
{
    float4 position : SV_POSITION;
    float4 color : COLOR;
};

VOut main(float4 position : POSITION)
{
    VOut output;

    output.position = position;
    output.color = float4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);

    return output;
}
```

Simple pixel shader:

```
float4 main(float4 position : POSITION, float4 color : COLOR) : SV_TARGET
{
    return color;
}
```

Rendering function is simply this:

```
void DirectXRendererImpl::Render(const RenderQueue& renderQueue, const RenderableLighting& lighting, const DebugOptions::RenderingMode debugMode, const DebugOptions::RenderingFlags debugExtra)
{
    const FLOAT clearColor[4] = { 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f };
    mContext->ClearRenderTargetView(mBackbuffer, clearColor);

    uint32_t vertexSize = sizeof(VERTEX);
    uint32_t offset = 0;
    mContext->IASetVertexBuffers(0, 1, &mVertexBuffer, &vertexSize, &offset);
    mContext->IASetPrimitiveTopology(D3D11_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY_TRIANGLELIST);

    mContext->Draw(3, 0);

    mSwapchain->Present(0, 0);
}
```

The app runs for a few seconds and then causes a full video driver reset. Is my app leaking memory or what is causing this?

EDIT: more specifically, this is the error:

```
First-chance exception at 0x0F69974F (nvwgf2um.dll) in ExampleGame.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00193000.
Unhandled exception at 0x0F69974F (nvwgf2um.dll) in ExampleGame.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00193000.
```

Comment: Can you try loading your program into the VS debugger? It'll tell you where exactly the error occurs. Also, the error you are getting is commonly known by its Unix name: a segmentation fault. It usually happens when you read past the end of an array or deference a null pointer.

Comment: The first thing you should do is to enable the [debug device](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2012/11/30/direct3d-sdk-debug-layer-tricks.aspx) and see if you get any CORRUPTION or ERROR messages from it. These are things that the driver is not expecting to happen in a well-behaved application.

Comment: As CW said, use a debug device. Also test all the functions that return a `HRESULT` and make sure they succeed. **The question is, when does it crash? On init, on render, on resize?** Use `OutputDebugString` to trace yourself through the execution flow for the lack of a better solution. And make sure you don't have FRAPS running while writing D3D stuff in debug mode! It'll mess up ref counting.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use this->

`bufferDescription.ByteWidth = sizeof(VERTEX) * sizeof(OurVertices);` otherwise program will be crashed.